# How to display different HTML sections as different pages of a website

Tags: html, forms, sections

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="main-container">
    <!--NAVAGATION-->
    <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#home"></a>Home</li>
    <li><a href="#about"></a>About</li>
    <li><a href="#robotics">Robotics</a></li>
    <li><a href="#books">Books</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="main-content">
    <section class="home section" id="home">
        <!--home page content-->
    </section>
    <section class="about section" id="about">
        <!--about page content-->
    </section>          
    <section class="robotics section" id="robotics">
         <!--robotics page content-->
    </section>
    <section class="books section" id="books">
         <!--books page content-->
    </section>
</div>
    
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hello, guys! I am playing with this structure and trying to link each sections to its corresponding NAV option so I can display only the content selected (as a different page). However with the structure of an "id" attribute in the section and "href" attribute to the NAV option doesn't help too much, because only switches the content on the page, not the page itself. I've tried my best to do this, but this is the best I could do.

Comment: What do you mean by "switch the page itself"? You have a single HTML document: that's a single page. The only way you can add more pages is by creating separate HTML documents entirely.

Comment: However I get the impression you want the browser's address bar to change - in which case you can use `window.history.replaceState(...)`, however this still requires your web-server to support serving the same document from all those "real" URIs now, otherwise you'll break users' bookmarks.

Comment: I'm a new programmer, so I don't know too much and I thought I could display different sections by clicking its corresponding NAV structure. But thanks for your attetion, I'm gonna try to make different HTML documents.

Comment: Dai, thank you! You helped me a lot. c:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the CSS pseudo class [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) to do this. Hide your sections by default and when one is clicked on, change that section's display to block:

```css
section {
  display: none;
}

section:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <!--NAVAGATION-->
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#robotics">Robotics</a></li>
    <li><a href="#books">Books</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="main-content">
  <section class="home section" id="home">
    home page content
  </section>
  <section class="about section" id="about">
    about page content
  </section>
  <section class="robotics section" id="robotics">
    robotics page content
  </section>
  <section class="books section" id="books">
    books page content
  </section>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
function show(shown, hidden) {
  document.getElementById(shown).style.display='block';
  document.getElementById(hidden).style.display='none';
  return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="Page1" style="background-color:powderblue;">
    <h1>Hello I am In Section One Without Refresh </h1>
    <a href="#" onclick="return show('Page2','Page1');">Show page 2</a>
  </div>

  <div id="Page2" style="display:none;background-color:black;color:white;">
    
    <h1>Hello I am In Section Two Without Refresh </h1>
    <a href="#" onclick="return show('Page1','Page2');">Show page 1</a>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

See You can Render Your Section Like This Using Javascript It's Looks Like One Page Website